# Passing "vector<string>" as function argument and I get an error

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

I've furthered in the realization of my save function and got the idea of passing my arguments as "vector" (because they are) instead of "string"
which gives this:

```
void saveFunction(ofstream& save, vector<string> site, vector<string> url, vector<string> username, vector<string> password)
{
    save << site;
    save << url;
    save << username;
    save << password;

}
```

which gives this error:

`error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream' {aka 'std::basic_ofstream<char>'} and 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >')`

Comment: There is non `<<` operator for `std::vector`. If you have a `std::vector<Foo>` what do you expect getting written into `save`?

Comment: What did you expect `save << site;` to do?

Comment: I've changed the title so it doesn't look like it's about rvalue references.

Comment: so for example `username` is several strings? Misnamed at least, probably misdesigned

Comment: You need a `struct` with fields `site`, `url`, `username`, `password` and then pass a const reference to vector of that struct, instead of 4 separate vectors

Comment: @sp2danny "so for example username is several strings?" I think OP wants to dump usernames, passwords, sites and urls.

Comment: Jabberwocky and melpomene : I expected the program to basically write the vector in a text file, so I can re-use it later, in other parts of my program

sp2danny : username is a vector<string> and I hoped that "save << username" would dump the whole vector in a text file.

Slava : Thanks a lot, honestly I didn't even know this existed. I chose vectors because I knew that it was possible to target an element in them and add/remove elements as the program goes. I'll investigate more on that.

Comment: @Solar There would be issues around overloading `<<` for *ForwardIterable* objects. For example, what do you use for a delimiter, and how could you specify that? Perhaps a *manipulator* but what form would that take? Also, what would you write for an empty container? In C++ things don't get implemented unless the specification is watertight.

Comment: @Slava excuse me, how would I add a new user input to a specific member in a struct? Because from what I saw, struct don't seem to be modifiable.

Comment: @Solar looks like you need a good textbook, SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: @Slava Thanks for the advice, I'm planning to get myself one soon. But in the meantime I want to do something fun. So could you please tell me if it is possible (and if it is how?) to add a new element into a specific struct's member?

Again, thanks a lot for all your answers ^^

Comment: @Solar Adding new members to existing structs runtime is not possible, C++ is statically typed

Comment: @Solar you just do it different way. If your data structure is dynamic and fields change in runtime then closest thing is `std::map<std::string,std::string>`

Comment: @Slava Thanks a lot for the advice, in the meantime I started reading the "C++ Primer 5th Edition" and I'm glued to it. Never knew it would make such a difference xD

Answer (score 3):

`ofstream` does not have an overloaded `<<` operator for a `std::vector`, so you need to roll one yourself, for example

```
for (auto&& s : username){
    save << s;
}
```

although your reasons for using a `std::vector` might be questionable.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the extraordinarily quick answer!
However, I don't get how I should use this...

(I'm a beginner who started 2 days ago)

Comment: @Solar: Pleasure, it's how we like to rock and roll on this site.

Comment: `for (auto&& s : username){` is a range based for loop used to iterate over the container. Look at the examples at the bottom of this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @Solar As a beginner, you might want to grab a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to help your learning.

Comment: @Bathsheba "move fast and break things" - when It's other peoples things it's all good ;)